# What's the idiomatic way of saying this?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What's the idiomatic way of saying this? The issue with the sentence I am thinking about is that it's a case of wrong comparison. Look at the word after "than" and you will see that the things compared don't match, how can I rephrase this?

For example:

> You can write a better script than Game of Thrones Season 8.

Comment: You say *the things compared don't match,* but the reality is that native Anglophones aren't that pedantic. Your example is perfectly natural English as it stands, and your objections seem to me to be just a misguided extension of [***strong type-checking***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) from *computer* languages to *natural language* contexts.

Comment: If it really bothers you you could say *you could write something better than...* but I agree that you're overthinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean that

- script is a written text;
- "Game of Thrones Season 8" is a collections of episodes in a series movie

and that they cannot be compared directly. You are right about it.

---

One way to mitigate this problem is:

> You can write a better script than **the one written for** Game of Thrones Season 8.